# what if i disagree with my question being put on hold

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Recently, my query generated the following message:  put on hold as too broad ... -specific users listed-.  Is it appropriate for me to contact each of the listed users, stating my reasons for disagreeing?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it appropriate for me to contact each of the listed users, stating my reasons for disagreeing?

No, please don't do that. If you edit a recently closed post to try and improve it, it's automatically put in a queue to be reviewed and possibly reopened. If that still doesn't work, you can click the "flag" link under the post and choose "in need of moderator intervention".

Your question seems fine, but was a bit verbose; I shortened it while trying not to remove any relevant information that the people answering it would need. It's reopened now.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the informative reply, and thanks for going to the trouble of editing my query.

Comment: Also, it is unlikely that any of the involved user would be able to _do_ anything about their vote once the question has been closed, unless one of them was a moderator (and in that case, the question may well have a good reason to remain closed, but nobody is perfect).

Comment: @Kusalananda: What do you mean by “it is unlikely that any of the involved user(s) would be able to *do* anything about their vote once the question has been closed”?   Anybody who cast a vote to close can also vote to reopen, unless their reputation fell below 3000 since they cast the close vote.   It’s true that none of them will be able to ***unilaterally*** reopen the question.

Comment: @user2661923: A point that doesn’t get made often enough, clearly enough (IMHO) is that,  while editing your question puts it into the Reopen Queue, all it takes is for three people to vote thumbs down (“leave closed”) for it to be knocked out of the review queue.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Therefore, if your question is put “on hold”, you should read all the comments and all the applicable help pages to try to figure out why it was closed, and what you need to do to fix it, and then do that *all as one edit*.  If you make a series of small edits, the question may get knocked out of the review queue before you’ve improved it enough to make people want to reopen it.

Comment: @Scott I was referring to the close vote that they  had cast. It can be retracted at any time until the question is actually closed. After that point, yes, reopen votes may be cast.

Comment: Gold tag badge holders can single-handedly re-open a question if it has the appropriate tag. (I imagine many meta readers know this...)

Comment: @StephenKitt I wonder if that is true. I've closed a bash question single handedly once and was not able to reopen it. I might be misremembering though...